# How do I decide which partition to replace with Linux on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I already have 4 primary partitions, and which one (if any) can I change to logical?](https://superuser.com/questions/341495/why-do-i-already-have-4-primary-partitions-and-which-one-if-any-can-i-change)

I want to dual boot Ubuntu. My Windows 7 PC came with a maximum of 4 partitions by default, so I must replace one of them with Ubuntu.

I examined the partitions with disk management. How do I decide which one to delete? Here are the four partitions.

[image: 4 Partitions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Make your HP recovery discs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01895783#WhenCreate), then you can delete the Recovery partition.

If you want to keep the recovery partition, then [see this article](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/How-to-repartition-HDD-of-HP-notebook-with-pre-loaded-Windows-7/m-p/742019) on how to properly create a 5th partition.

Comment: Sigh ... thank you. (See my latest question http://superuser.com/questions/386543/how-do-i-recover-windows-7-after-a-rash-ubuntu-install). I really should have read your reply earlier :( :( :(

Comment: Not sure what Ubuntu does to the windows partitions, but you might try what PI3ppp suggested in your new question, if Windows boots make your HP recovery media, then use disk managment to see if any partitions were changed to dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

The only one big enough to hold a Linux installation of average size is the D drive. This drive is currently your recovery drive.  If you value the ability to re-install your computer's Windows OS I would not install on that partition either.  What I would do is resize your C: drive and assign however much space you are willing to dedicate to a Linux installation.  Then leave that space un-formatted and allow your Linux installer to format that partition during installation.

Comment: Thank you. What are HP-Tools and system? If HP-Tools is not important, can I get rid of that partition, and create a new partition out of freed memory from C: ?

Comment: it may hold system drivers and other software specific to your PC should be available  online for download from HP's website but I would verify that before you delete it.

Comment: No.  It's the [system volume](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html) and it is necessary for [bootstrapping Windows](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-boot-process.html).